# Function cannot be applied to () Android Studio (because of View v)

Tags: java, android

I am building a very small android app that basically shows a time picker when the user clicks a checkbox

```
public Boolean HourTurnOnClicked(View v) {
        CheckBox HourTurnOnButton = findViewById(R.id.HourTurnOnCheck);
        if(HourTurnOnButton.isChecked()) {
            showTimePickerDialog();
            return true;
        }
        return null;
}

public void showTimePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

And when a time is chosen by the user, this time is printed in a little Textbox. By default the Textbox has the "8:00 AM" value so I started making a function that checks if the HourTurnOnButton is checked and if yes, it updates the time displayed in the Textbox. Here is what I made

```
    public void UpdateHourToTurnOn(View v) {
        TextView HourToTurnOnText = findViewById(R.id.HourToTurnOn);
        if(HourTurnOnClicked()) {
            //print the chosen hour
        }
    }
```

But Android studio tells me that there is an error in my if :

```
error: method HourTurnOnClicked in class MainActivity cannot be applied to given types;
        if(HourTurnOnClicked()) {
           ^
  required: View
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I understand that the problem is related to the View in my HourTurnOn function but why this is making that trouble to Android Studio ? How can I solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't passed in the argument for `HourTurnOnClicked` method

Change it to this

```
if(HourTurnOnClicked(v)) {
    //print the chosen hour
}
```

Comment: I come from the Python world where function arguments are separated by comas. I have seen like 10 times this (View v) in android studio tutorials but what does that mean, what is this ? And when we type (View v), don't we give two arguments (View and v) to the function ? Why android studio says my function has one argument ?

Comment: `View` is the type of the variable and `v` is the name of the variable. This is Java Syntax. While in android, `View` can represent the widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Boolean HourTurnOnClicked() {
    CheckBox HourTurnOnButton = findViewById(R.id.HourTurnOnCheck);
    if(HourTurnOnButton.isChecked()) {
        showTimePickerDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Try removing the View argument of the HourTurnOnClicked() function

Comment: I tried this but since it is needed to do CheckBox stuff, when I click the button on my phone, the app crashes

Comment: So, try to assign the checkbox view as the argument